# New User, Please Help with PassPhrase Question

Tags: passphrase

We are new users to Ubuntu, and completed the dvd disk installation.  Now the before logging in, Ubuntu is requesting a PassPhrase.  We did not recall creating a PassPhrase, only a password.  Can someone please assist us?

Comment: Please let us know a bit more about your Ubuntu version, when is the passphrase asked? After or before password?

Comment: We have the lastest version of ubuntu 14.04 and now we reinstalled ubuntu to by pass the headache of the passphrase, but now our system is freezing up.  We converted from XP.  Any suggestions/

Comment: That is strange. I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and it is not at all presenting the problem you mentioned. It is working the way it did in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you made your home folder encrypted.

Take a look on **[this article](http://ads.tt/YURN)**, maybe will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We decided to just reinstall ubuntu, now the system is freezing up.  This is so frustrating, we had really high expectations for ubuntu.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In what exactly moment the system is freezing?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (passphrase).

My solution that worked was to switch my boot location in the start-up routine (boot PROM) 
from "Hard Disk" to "CDROM".

I had previously loaded a Linux version and encrypted it.